# way in xcode to see which other apps are running?

Tags: iphone, xcode, command, utility

I'm programming for iphone 4 and was wondering if there was a way to see which other apps are using the internet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your mac, you could try iStat Menus (or mistat on the Mac App Store). On your iPhone, not possible.

Comment: You can see what network connections are open (if you're prepared to use sysctl() and do some work groveling around in kernel data structures) (there is a "netstat" app for the iphone, after all), but figuring out what app owns a particular connection is harder.